# Javascript variable hoisting blockwise

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I have two blocks of code:

Code Block A:

```
function test() {
  var testBool = true;

     if(!testBool) {
        var temp = 10;
     } else {
        temp = 20;  
     }
     console.log(temp);
  }
```

and Code Block B:

```
function test() {
  var testBool = true;
  var array = [1,2];

  _.each(array, (item) => {
     if(!testBool) {
        var temp = 10;
      } else {
        temp = 20;
      }
  });
  console.log(temp);
}
```

For 'A', it prints **20** which is fine. For 'B', it throws **reference error**. Instead of *_.each*, if i use an inner function, it throws the same error. I am trying to understand variable and function hoisting. If for 'A' the variable *temp* is being hoisted to top of the function, why is it not happening for 'B' or an inner function ?

Comment: variable is hoisted within the same function.

Comment: Well, it *is* hoisted to the top of the function. Of the *inner* function, in B, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by "*if i use an inner function instead of `_.each`*"? You already are using a nested function with `_.each`.

Comment: @Bergi that's the clarification i wanted ..thanks ! So, if-else blocks are part of the same function but functions such as _.each have their own scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If for 'A' the variable temp is being hoisted to top of the function

"**top of the function**" (it is declared within)

> why is it not happening for 'B' or an inner function ?

Because it is declared inside a **different** function.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it is declared within' ?

Comment: A variable declaration is hoisted to the top of the function that the declaration is inside. It isn't hoised to the top of a different function. Not even if the first function is inside the different function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope, which means that variable symbols are visible within the function they are declared in.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

So in the second example, temp is declared out of scope of the console.log statement (hence reference error).

Hoisting just means that they are available in the complete function body and not only after the line they are declared (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)